# Azure Web Sites - Remove X-Powered-By Header from PHP

Tags: php, azure, http-headers

I want to remove the *X-Powerd-By* header that PHP exposes in Azure Web Sites.

I've already removed all headers that expose software versions in *web.config* file.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But there are two of them.

The one coming from ASP.Net is gone. But the second one can only be turned off in *php.ini* with

```
expose_php = off
```

I can't override the value in *.user.ini* since it can only be changed in the *php.ini* itself, which is unreachable.

Can this only be done by providing my own PHP Version for the Azure Web Site? Because there I can change the *php.ini* file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know ( and I've tried this a few times ), there is not a way to do this through configuration.  However, you can do it programmatically.  Not the ideal solution, but it works.  Put this at the top of your page file.

```
<?php header_remove("X-Powered-By"); ?>
```

Note: This would be in addition to your existing web.config setting that removes the X-Powered-By header for ASP.NET.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. I'm unfamiliar with PHP in-general, but I applied this change to the top and bottom of page.php in a custom WordPress theme and it had no effect, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @martin_costello mybe your php code is not interpreted in the theme. Just open up another question with code details and someone will help you here

Comment: I fixed this for myself in an alternative way, which I'll add here now as an alternative answer.

Comment: Use @MartinCostello answer for a no php.ini  app-wide solution.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer here didn't work for me when I tried to remove this header from a WordPress site, but the following URL Rewrite rule did most of the job for me by blanking the header's value, rather than completely removing it.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
        <rule name="Remove X-Powered-By HTTP response header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-Powered-By" pattern=".+" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  <system.webServer/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works on azure gov with php app on 3/6/18. thanks

Comment: After trying other solutions out, this seems to work. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: worked for me too instead of editing the php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htacess if you are on an Azure Linux Web service

```
php_value expose_php off
```